# More elegant way to include different content based on value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

Is there a more elegant way to write this code, perhaps by defining an array `[[1, "test1"], [2, "test2"], …]`?

```
<%- if c.current_state == 1 %>
Test1
<% elsif c.current_state == 2 %>
Test2
<% elsif c.current_state == 3 %>
Test3
<% elsif c.current_state == 4 %>
Test4
<% elsif c.current_state == 5 %>
Test5
<% elsif c.current_state == 6 %>
Test6
<% end %>
```

Comment: You can start off by not having mystery numbers in your code.  Perhaps make `current_state` return a Ruby symbol instead.

Comment: If your code works consider moving it to [codereview.se].

Comment: Don't be rude to those trying to help you.

Comment: @theTinMan This question, in its current form, is too abstract, hypothetical, and unclear to qualify for Code Review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your view you could achieve the same thing simply with

```
Test<%= c.current_state %>
```

so I can't give you further advice without more details. But you should read up on [Enumerable](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html):

Using [`map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-map)

```
1.upto(6).map {|v| "test#{v}" }
```

would give you

```
["test1", "test2", "test3", "test4", "test5", "test6"]
```

Using `map.with_index`

```
1.upto(6).map.with_index {|v| [v, "test#{v}"] }
```

would give you your requested array

```
[[1, "test1"], [2, "test2"], [3, "test3"], [4, "test4"], [5, "test5"], [6, "test6"]]
```

Using [`inject`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject)

```
1.upto(6).inject({}) {|h,k| h[k] = "test#{k}"; h }
```

would give you

```
{1=>"test1", 2=>"test2", 3=>"test3", 4=>"test4", 5=>"test5", 6=>"test6"}
```